# FullCalendar and Multiple Dynamic Event Sources

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I have FullCalendar (1.6.4) working with a single JSON feed (a single user's calendar). Now, I want to enhance the functionality so the calendar will display multiple user calendars (the admin and their child account calendars). Until the calendar is called, I won't know how many user calendars will be called. So, I have a Ajax function call a PHP script that returns a JSON feed of all user ID's for the admin account.

```
$(document).ready(getUsers);

function getUsers() {
    var data = $.ajax( {
        url: '/s/calendar_userdata.php',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(userData) {
            var user_count = userData.length;
            var uid_array = [];

            // Create the sources
            for (var i = 0; i < user_count; i++)
            {
                var uid = userData[i].uid;
                if(!uid_array[i]) uid_array[i] = [];
                uid_array[i] = uid;
            }
        }
    });
    loadCal();
}
```

The Ajax call works. I get an array (uid_array) such as [7,47] back, as expected. I would like to use this array within my loadCal function as illustrated below, but I can't get it to persist after the getUsers function has concluded.

```
function loadCal() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        eventSources: [
        {
            url: '/s/events.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data:
            {
                uid: uid_array
            }
        }
        ],
        editable: true,
        .........
```

I've tried:
1) Creating a global variable by initially defining uid_array outside of getUsers without the "var". 
2) Setting "window.uid_array = uid_array;" within the getUsers function.
3) Adding "return uid_array;" at the end of the getUsers function.
4) Adding a closure at the end of the getUsers function. But, I don't grasp them well enough to believe I did it correctly.

I have 2 questions:
1) How do I make the array (uid_array) available outside of getUsers?
2) In what format does the array need to be so that fullCalendar will recognize and use it?

I've been stuck on this for a while. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you change the location of `loadCal` function you can accomplish your objective:

```
function getUsers() {
    var data = $.ajax( {
        url: '/s/calendar_userdata.php',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(userData) {
            var user_count = userData.length;
            var uid_array = [];

            // Create the sources
            for (var i = 0; i < user_count; i++)
            {
                var uid = userData[i].uid;
                if(!uid_array[i]) uid_array[i] = [];
                uid_array[i] = uid;
            }
            //CALL loadCal FROM HERE
            loadCal(uid_array);
        }
    });
}
```

Modify `loadCal` to accept array of uids:

```
function loadCal(uidArray) {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventSources: [
    {
        url: '/s/events.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data:
        {
            uid: uidArray
        }
    }
    ],
    editable: true,
```

When you are making `ajax` call in `getUsers` it is not returned and `loadCal` is called. So you need to make sure that it is called only after ajax is returned that is in `success` callback.

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot. I knew it would be a small adjustment...I just couldn't find it. Thanks.